# How to ask a question of a professor?

Tags: word-usage, grammar, prepositions, phrase-meaning

I want to pose some questions to a professor who know me very all. It's important for me to ask my questions politely. The problem is that I even don't know how to start.As We have a oral reproduction of story course in this term; I want to ask her if the choice of my story is suitable or not.and then i want to attach the story pdf file at the end. I need your help. pleaseeeeeeee

Comment: **who know me very all** is not grammatical.  I think you mean to say **who doesn't know me very well at all**.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems to be a question on manners, and no clue is given about why the social situation calls for anything other than normal manners.

Answer (score 1):

**Would you please...** {do something}

is polite without being obsequious.

However, the standards of politeness may vary from country to country and from professor to professor, and what passes for politeness in one place or with one person may be considered rather too informal in another place or by another person.

Comment: Or "is it okay if . . .?" I'm sure that any reasonable professor will be just fine with any student asking a question. (That should be part of their job.) The words used are less important than the tone of voice. Most people will forgive even culturally insulting language if the question comes from somebody new to the culture who is carrying themself in a respectful and sincere manner.